# How to reproject a list of shapefiles (SpatialLinesDataFrame) in R

Tags: r, lapply, shapefile, r-raster

I read a list of shapefiles (SpatialLinesDataFrame) onto R. Now I am trying to reproject this list to a ndifferent EPSG but I just can't seem to have it work. I have tried with lapply and looping through the list but none seem to work, which keep giving the errors I show below.

I know my example is not reproducible, but I might just be missing something very obvious because I could not find a straight forward answer to this.

```
EPSG_102033 <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs" # CRS EPSG:102033 string

files <- list.files(files_path, pattern = ".shp$", full.names = TRUE)

roads <- setNames(lapply(files, shapefile), tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files))) # this gives a list of three SpatialLinesDataFrame S4 objects

### I have tried:

roads <- lapply(files, function(x) {x <- spTransform(x, CRSobj = EPSG_102033);x}) 

# which gives: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spTransform’ for signature ‘"character", "character"’

### Also tried:

for (i in length(roads)){
  roads[[i]] <- spTransform(roads[i],  CRSobj = EPSG_102033) 
}

# which gives: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spTransform’ for signature ‘"list", "character"’
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `st_transform` instead of `spTransform`? Check the class of your objects, the former is the "newer version" of reprojection from the package `sf`  and the latter is from an older generation, hence the "unable to find inherited method" error. There was a similar issue from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/307432). The following should work:

```
library(sf)
EPSG_102033 <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs" # CRS EPSG:102033 string

files <- list.files(files_path, pattern = ".shp$", full.names = TRUE)

roads <- setNames(lapply(files, shapefile), tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files))) # this gives a list of three SpatialLinesDataFrame S4 objects

### Method 1

roads <- lapply(files, function(x) {x <- st_transform(x, CRSobj = EPSG_102033);x}) 


### Method 2

for (i in length(roads)){
  roads[[i]] <- st_transform(roads[i],  CRSobj = EPSG_102033) 
}
```

Hope that helps!